# Mobile app that adds appointments and reminders to smartphone calendar

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, smartphone

I am looking to build an app to be used on smartphones that can store appointments with reminders set on the smartphone's calendar.

My options are to build this as a responsive web application that can run on iphone, android and blackberry or to build native mobile apps for the different platforms.

My question is, is what I'm trying to do possible, either as a web app or as mobile apps?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the calendar if you're on a native application.

You do not have direct access to the calendar if you're on a web application.

However, a third and popular solution is to build the majority of the application as a web application, but then build a native application which wraps the web app in a WebKit View and has a small amount of code to process calendar requests.  This way you'd be spending 80% of your time working on the app for web, then 20% to build the wrappers.  Another perk of this is that you already have a web version of it done, for devices for which you don't build wrappers.

The disadvantage of doing this is that you lose some responsiveness in touch and you also lose the native look and feel of the device.  You can try to approximate it with different themes that use similar graphics but it still won't "feel" 100% native.